# white-space-collapse wont work

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm working on an XSL, XML to convert something PDF

XML:

```
<name>
Name:
</name>
<name_line>            </name_line> //this is used for my line
```

XSL:

```
<fo:block white-space-collapse="false">
<fo:inline>
<xsl:value-of select="student/name" />
</fo:inline>
<fo:inline>
<xsl:value-of select="student/name_line" />
</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

I want to output Name:***_*__*_***

How to do this? white-space-collapse="false" just wont work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to collapse the white space, so you want white-space-collapse="true" not "false".

```
       <fo:block white-space-collapse="true">
            <fo:inline>
                Name:
            </fo:inline>
            <fo:inline>
                Kevin Brown
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
```

Yields:

Name: Kevin Brown